# Is there a way using store inside a static method?

Tags: angular, static-methods, ngrx-store

I need to dispatch an action inside a static function. Is there a way to do this and is it a good practice?

Comment: Its good to not to have static functions that are not stateless nor have sidefects.

Comment: I concur with @Antoniossss, that would not be awesome. Plus it's not always the best practice to make inheritance in Angular (components).